# Find first occurence of index and keep that row

Tags: python, numpy

I have an ndarray with the following content:

```
[0, 1]
[0, 5]
[1, 7]
[2, 9]
[2, 4]
[2, 4]
[3, 8]
[4, 2]
[4, 7]
```

Now I'd like to keep only the first row when the first element is the same for multiple rows. Would result in:

```
[0, 1]
[1, 7]
[2, 9]
[3, 8]
[4, 2]
```

**How can I achieve this with numpy?**

Comment: Look into `np.unique(....return_index)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an input data as:

```
x = np.array([
    [0, 1],
    [0, 5],
    [1, 7],
    [2, 9],
    [2, 4],
    [2, 4],
    [3, 8],
    [4, 2],
    [4, 7],
])
```

Then you could use `numpy.unique` with the `return_index` set to true (as @divakar mentioned in the commend) in order to find the unique indices of the first elements.

```
idx = numpyp.unique(x[:,0], return_index=True)[1]
```

Then you can just access them as:

```
x[idx]
```

Hope this helps.